# Where do I find Visual Studio Team explorer error details?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

When I open the *Pending Changes* tab in Visual Studio Team Explorer, it says that "One or more errors occurred." Where can I find details on what kind(s) of error have occurred?

Some background: We have recently upgraded our source code repository from TFS 2010 to Azure DevOps Server 2020 (with TFS 2015 as a required intermediate step), in the process moving from one server to another. After switching the URL in Visual Studio, developers started getting this error message. Apart from that, everything seems to be working fine. Pending changes are displayed, check-in/check-out works.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Hi Joseph Schröer,  Any update on this ticket? Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such related logs stored in TFS/Azure DevOps side.

For TFS/Azure DevOps, the installation log file generally store in `temp` folder.

Typically this folder is : `C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Local\Temp`

And the Configuration logs stored in:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs
```

The logs should be stored accordingly in case of TFS version upgrade.

In your situation, sometimes if you are working with multiple TFS account /TFS version in the same system then TFS caches something and throws the error . So, for this you can clear the TFS cache and check if this work.

You can clear TFS’s cache from following location:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache
```

Once cache will delete, probably TFS will ask for credential to reconnect. You need to provide valid credentials.

If you still get similar errors after above steps, I would suggest you also clear Visual Studio cache, which may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the visual studio and reopened and it got fixed.